# QSound play sounds one after another

Tags: windows, qt, audio, qt4.7

I'm working on a program that receive an event every 200ms, and I want to play a sound depending on the last event received when the last sound playing is finished.
Unfortunately the isFinished() function doesn't work on windows for unlooped sounds.

So I'm trying to find a way to wait until a sound has finished playing before playing an other one from the last event (like a LIFO with only one element).

I manage to do that :

```
QSound *sound[5];
int select, lastSelect;

if(sound[lastSelect]->loopsRemaining() >=1)
  sound[lastSelect]->stop();
else {
  sound[select]->setLoops(2);
  sound[select]->play();
  lastSelect = select;
}
```

But it's queuing the sounds and that's not what I want.
Otherwise I can do it by setting the number of loop to 2 but it plays the sound twice before playing the next one.

Do you have any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Maybe you look for using Phonon: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-demos-qmediaplayer-mediaplayer-h.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out